# Calculate GPS coordinates

Tags: matrix-equations

There are 3 satellites with coordinates $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ for $i=1,2,3$

Sat1 = (-11, -10, 21)
Sat2 = (-12, -20,11)
Sat3 = (14,-10,19)

There is a receiver, somewhere in the middle with certain distance to Sat 1,2 and 3

d$_1$ = 22,1, d$_2$ = 21,5 and d$_3$ = 21,5.

I want to determine the coordinates $x, y,z$ of the receiver. So we have to solve the system of equations:

$(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 + (z-z_1)^2 = \text{d}_1^2\qquad$ (E1)

$(x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2 + (z-z_2)^2 = \text{d}_2^2\qquad$ (E2)

$(x-x_3)^2 + (y-y_3)^2 + (z-z_3)^2 = \text{d}_3^2.\qquad$ (E3)

To eliminate the quadratic terms in E1, E2 and E3 we will create three new equations without any quadratic variables, namely: E1-E2, E1-E3 and E2-E3.

Putting these 3 equations in matrix notation we will find that
$
\begin{pmatrix}
d_1^2 - d_2^2\\ d_1^2 - d_3^2\\ d_2^2 - d_3^2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-2(x_1-x_2) & -2(y_1-y_2) & -2(z_1-z_2) \\
-2(x_1-x_3) & -2(y_1-y_3) & -2(z_1-z_3) \\
-2(x_2-x_3) & -2(y_2-y_3) & -2(z_2-z_3)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^2-x_2^2+y_1^2-y_2^2+z_1^2-z_2^2\\ x_1^2-x_3^2+y_1^2-y_3^2+z_1^2-z_3^2 \\ x_2^2-x_3^2+y_2^2-y_3^2+z_2^2-z_3^2
\end{pmatrix}.
$

SciLab now tells me that the matrix is singular, how?!

Comment: Shouldn't L.H.S be $d_1^2-d_2^2$, $d_1^2-d_3^2$ and $d_2^2-d_3^2$?

Comment: Yep, I edited the post. Now it is okay

Answer (score 0):

This matrix is singular because the 2nd row minus the 3rd row equals the 1st row.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1-x_2 & y_1-y_2 & z_1-z_2 \\
x_1-x_3 & y_1-y_3 & z_1-z_3 \\
x_2-x_3 & y_2-y_3 & z_2-z_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So what you've done is, for example, to solve the below system of equations:
\begin{align}
x^2+x&=2\\
x^2+y&=3\\
x^2+z&=4\\
\end{align}
you subtracted to get:
\begin{align}
y-x&=1\\
z-y&=1\\
z-x&=2\\
\end{align}

You can't do this way. You should solve at least one quadratic equation to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, your problem has two solutions. The planes $E_1-E_2$ and $E_1-E_3$ intersect in a line $D$. Find the intersection of $D$ and $E_1$ ($2$ points) and you are done.